# Can the primary email of a Google account be changed to something other than the Gmail address?

Tags: gmail, account-management, google-account

I've added a Gmail address to my Google account and now it is stuck and displayed as the primary address:

> david.black.co.at@gmail.com    (Primary email)
> david@dasz.at  Remove

Is there a way to force my real address as primary?

Alternatively, if I don't actually need the Gmail address can I delete it so that only my other address remains and, if so, would that create problems with other applications (e.g. Google Code) connected to this account?

---

Note: That's my real address, which I publish everywhere including on my profile here. I don't mind exposing it as it's one of the few pieces of info about me that are in the public-domain.

Comment: If that's your real email I'd recommend changing it in this post

Comment: then it would be even better to delete this post and create a new one with fake addresses. if this posts stays online, even in changed form, the original address will be visible in the history.

Comment: That's my real address, which I publish everywhere (including my profile here). It is one of the few truly public domain pieces of info about me ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way currently, and its *infuriating*. I had to create a completely seperate account to use the Android Marketplace, since Checkout will only accept a @gmail.com address and its painful to see that address on every Google service I use. Not to mention that it breaks some services (eg Wave) that have their own accounts data and only use the Google account name to link them up.

I know that there are big changes on the way for the whole way that Google does account management (the "more services in Apps" thing is part of it), but I'm not privy to all the details. I'll raise a ruckus about anything thats not fixed once they roll all that stuff out :)

Comment: 3.5 years later it's still not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just remove the Gmail service from your account (after making sure any possibly useful information from it is backed up). If you don't already have alternate email choices, you should be prompted to add one so your account will still have a username once Gmail is deleted.

It's possible that your displayed username for services like Google Code will change (since it seems to use the primary email address if the account in question doesn't use Gmail) but there should be no real problems, only changes in how your profile appears.

Searching through the Google Accounts help documentation, I can't find anything on changing your Primary Address if you use Gmail; it seems to be a choice made for you.

**Edit (prompted by Robert Norris):** I would very much love such a feature, as I am prevented from logging into my AdSense account using the same username as every other Google service I use. If I could link the two Google Accounts, I would probably stop hating Google for shutting down Notepad and Jaiku (but not for shuttering Gizmo5, even though I already have an account).

Comment: I didn't find anything to delete my gmail account.

Answer (score -1):

settings -> "accounts and import". next to the listed email addresses you should see a "make default" link.

click it.

to remove that associated  gmail-address: choose the "delete" link.

Comment: The david@dasz.at address is already marked as default within GMail. The problem is the Google *Account*.