# How do I change my primary Gmail email address on Google Accounts

Tags: gmail, google-account

The primary email address for my Google account is a Gmail address.

How do I change the primary email address on my Google account?

Comment: I fail to see what the issue is.  There is no primary email account with Google.  There are recovery email addresses and these can be Google or non-Google.  However if you are reading email in the browser, it defaults to a account, giving you the impression that it is the primary account.  It isn't and this can be changed.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that you can do that. I would suggest loggin with your other GMail account that you want to make it primary and then [add](https://www.google.com/accounts/EditUserInfo) the old one as an additional email address to connect them.

You could also forward all your email from one to another or simply retrieve them via POP, if it is only for your emails.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill out a form (contact Google) to do this. [Here](https://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=verify_new_email) is the form.

Comment: Allready tried this - it says:Please enter a valid email address. Gmail addresses are not accepted on this form.

Answer (score 1):

A Gmail email address will always be the primary email address of a Google account having Gmail, also an email address that is the primary email address of a Google account can't be used as the primary or alternative email address of a different account.

While it is possible to remove a Gmail address from a Google account that email address will not be possible to be used again.

Considering the above, what you are trying, change the primary email address and keeping the original primary email address, in other words having two Gmail address in one Google account, **is not possible**.

Related

- [Can I change my Gmail email address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/93/88163)
- [Can the primary email of a Google account be changed to something other than the Gmail address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1119/88163)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add alternative email address to your gmail account then delete your gmail account. Remember if you delete you gmail account all the account accosted with gmail has been deleted. http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32046

Comment: The link points to the wrong help article "Delete your Google Account"

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, your only option is to forward the old email address to the new one, and transfer ownership of the things (eg blogs, feeds, albums) you have created with the old one to the new one.