# How to set my alternate (non-Gmail) address as the account primary?

Tags: google-account

I'm a big fan of Google services in general, and use quite a few of them.  I don't happen to use Gmail though.  I do have a Gmail address as part of my account, but I don't ever check it.  I have added my regular email account as an alternate in my account settings, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the alternate address the primary one.  Because of this I never get any notices from my account because they all go to Gmail, which I never look at.

This page: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1045580?hl=en#
has a note about setting the alternate address as the primary by first deleting it, but gives no further information on what to do next.  OK, I've deleted it about a dozen times now but I still can't set it as the primary address.

Comment: You could always set your Gmail to autoforward everything to the email address you actually use.

Comment: See also: [How do I change my primary Gmail email address on Google Accounts](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16881)

Comment: See also: [Change Google's notion of primary email address](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1119)

Comment: I saw those posts.  Thx.  I was hoping that things had perhaps changed in the 3+ years since that first one.  Alas.

Answer (score 1):

Google consumer accounts only admits non @gmail.com address when the account doesn't have a @gmail.com address.

If your account has an @gmail.com address, you should first cancel the account Gmail address.

**References**
[Change your username - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=19870)